# Python Change strings in list into numbers

Tags: python

For example:

```
mylist = [[ '.', 'm', '.', '.' ],['.', '.', '.', 'm']]
```

How would I loop through the list and change the m string to a zero?

Comment: All of the elements of the lists are strings. What are your actual criteria? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension

```
>>> [[0 if j == 'm' else j for j in i] for i in mylist]
[['.', 0, '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too:

```
mylist = [[ '.', 'm', '.', '.' ],['.', '.', '.', 'm']]

mylist = [list("".join(elem).replace('m','0')) for elem in mylist]
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[['.', '0', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '0']]
```